# java.lang.SecurityException when using "grantUriPermission" on URI

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions, android-image

I received several crash report by my app with a `java.lang.SecurityException`. This occurs when the app try to obtain a persistent permission on a image URI user chosed from its images.
The method to choose images is through an intent:

```
public static Intent openGalleryToSelectImages(Activity a)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Set action
    if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    }
    else {
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    }
    // Set MIME type and allow multiple selection
    intent.setType("image/*");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    }
    a.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), Communication.REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGES_FROM_GALLERY);

    return intent;
}
```

Then I execute some things on the received array of URIs.
The crash occurs when, for each URI, I try to get persistent read permission:

```
activity.grantUriPermission(activity.getPackageName(), uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
activity.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but I cannot figure out what's wrong with that.
In addiction to this, the app works fine on several smartphones, so it seems bound to a specific vendor.

EDIT:
I cannot perform deep analysis on devices caused crash.
On my development device the URI for the images is something like:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A796
```

Comment: crash in Noguat Device?? If so,check this Blog [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en).

Comment: whats your `uri` like? try to call `Log.d` and watch the logcat

Comment: I cannot check the URIs in the devices which caused the crash. On my development device the URIs are something like:
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A796

Comment: you dont own `com.android.providers.media.documents` content provider so you cannot grant any rights to that uri

Comment: But on my development devices it works fine (3 smartphones and 1 tablet). Do you mean the URI is different in others device? The `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/ima‌​ge%3A796` was an example about one of my device, but I think it will change on others manufacturer device.

Comment: dont you think that what you are trying to do makes no sense? what would be permissions good for if ANYBODY could grant rights to forbidden resource? only the owner of some resource can do that, not you

Comment: I followed the guide here [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/documen‌​t-provider.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/documen‌​t-provider.html) and I though my app must require the persistent permission to the URI which is given back to my app when user select the image. In that page they say:
`To prevent this from happening, you can persist the permissions that the system gives your app. Effectively, your app "takes" the persistable URI permission grant that the system is offering. This gives the user continued access to the files through your app`

Answer (score 1):

You can't grant permissions to yourself.

You ask another app, such as Gallery, to give you an Uri to a resource and if that app is well written, it will grant your app read access to that Uri upon return.

Unfortunately some Gallery apps (including that of a prominent Android phone manufacturer) don't grant you anything.

This is how we end up having to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission anyway. It also means that you need to request the runtime permission on Android 6+ when appropriate.

I ended up catching the `SecurityException` and requesting runtime permission at that moment - when I absolutely needed it.

Lesson learned the hard way: When you get back positive result in `onRequestPermissionsResult`, your activity is in stopped state. You can't save state and will lose any changes to member variables if you leave immediately (like by calling `startActivity` in the callback). Put what you need into member variables now but defer `startActivity` to `onResume`.

Comment: The images selection is performed using Gallery or other Android internal way I suppose. I achieve it using `a.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), Communication.REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGES_FROM_GALLERY);` as you can read in main post.

Comment: @Noisemaker I know, and that Gallery is responsible for granting you Uri permission. You can't obviously grant Uri permissions to yourself. Either you have the permission to read anything (in manifest and at runtime on Android 6+), or you're granted the permission to read a Uri by another app (like Gallery) upon requesting the Uri, or you don't have the permission at all. And when you don't have the permission you can't grant it to yourself. Does that make sense? **You don't call `grantUriPermission`, Gallery is supposed to do that.**

Comment: You call `grantUriPermission` if other app requests image from your content provider in your app. Not the other way around.

Comment: When I read this page [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) I though my app should call the method `grantUriPermission` to achieve a persistent permission on those file.

Comment: @Noisemaker Nowhere on that page it mentions `grantUriPermission`. It only mentions **`takePersistableUriPermission` but that only works if the other app called `grantUriPermission`**, which is not the case.

Comment: Ok I got the point! So the app to which I ask for images should be able to grant me those permission and I need to persist them on my app due to read the files later. What if the other app does not grant me permission? I need to write my own file selector?

Comment: @Noisemaker You don't need custom selector. You still get back the Uri from Gallery. It only crashes (SecurityException) when you attempt to read it. You can catch the exception, save the Uri to variable and [request runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) to read external storage. When user grants you permission, you can read from saved Uri.